# how to decode an json array returned to a angular button click

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am trying to get the key value pairs that is return from a mysql query to an angular call. On click I get the three rows I want (see results below).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="empcontroller">
<form>
Fistname    <input type="text" ng-model="emp_no" /><br/>
Secondname  <input type="text" ng-model="first_name" /><br/>
Thirdname   <input type="text" ng-model="last_name" /><br/>

<button ng-click="postData()">Submit</button><br>
</form>
</div>



<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('empcontroller', function($scope, $http)
               {

               $scope.postData = function () {

               var Indata = { what_to_do: "angular_users5",  where_clause: '[{"sqlvalue1":"a_earchvalue1","sqlvalue2":"b_earchvalue2"}]' }

               var req =
               {
                    method: 'POST',url: 'angular_master.php',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                    params: Indata
               }

               $http(req).then(function (response)
               {
                        $scope.names = response.data.records;
                               alert("i am here");

                        .. at this point I need the key value pair or each rows from the results below

                });

               }


               });

</script>
```

The data return from the php query is:

```
{
    "records":[
        {
            "Name":"Joe",
            "City":"Doe",
            "Country":"w"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Joe1",
            "City":"Doe1",
            "Country":"w1"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Joe2",
            "City":"Doe2",
            "Country":"w2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since I get 3 rows back I like to assign the names to the first name, second name,thirdname fields in the form.

Thanks

Comment: You have emp_no, first_name, last_name in your view, but Name, City Country in your data - what do you want to do?

Comment: I like to assign the first's row name assign to first name. Second row name return to variable second name.. etc

Comment: Can you try to improve your sample? I mean the view model variables are different from the data model variables and also different from the labels in the view. Your model keys are Name, City, Country, but the values are Firstname, SecondName, ThirdName ?

Comment: Let me try this sample. How do I break up the scope.name in the postdate function so I can post just a certain row like row 2 to the html
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="empcontroller">

<p id="demo">demo</p>
<p id="name">value1</p>
<p id="city">value2</p>
<p id="Country">value3</p>
<button ng-click="postData()">Submit</button><br>
</div>

Comment: I updated my answer (see "submitOne(n)" versus "submitAll(names)". Just add these functions to your controller scope variable and do whatever you want with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me everything looks fine (except your strange naming conventions). You can now use the data in your view.

```
<form>
    <div ng-repeat="n in names tracked by $index">
        <h3>{{$index + 1}}. Name:</h3>
        Firstname: <input ng-model="n.Name" /><br />
        Secondname: <input ng-model="n.City" /><br />
        Lastname: <input ng-model="n.Country" /><br />
        <button type="button" ng-click="submitOne(n)">Save this</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submitAll(names)">Save all</button>
</form>
```

Angular will decode your Json String from the server response into a Json Object automatically.
Just take care that your server sends a JSON header, so that Angular understands the format.

```
// add this to your server script (example: php), before you output the data
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Btw. you should not use Content-Type: undefined.
Use:

```
Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
```

Furthermore you are doing a POST request - which is fine, but you use "params" to add data to your request. You should use the "data" key, because "params" will add GET parameters.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET
>   parameters.
>
> data – {string|Object} – Data to be sent as the request
>   message data.

Comment: Thanks it helping me get an understand